# Get Settings value from another project C#

Tags: c#, web-config, settings

I have two projects Management.Api and Management.Repository. Management.Api has a Settings file with bunch of properties. Then when I started working with Management.Repository I realized I needed two more properties (let's call them PropA and PropB) so I added another Settings file to Management.Repository instead of adding those properties in Management.Api > Settings so I don't have to pass it all the way down to Management.Repository from Management.Api.

Now I'm wondering is there a way to add PropA and ProbB to Management.Api > Settings and access those from Management.Repository.

Note: I have seen solution saying I can link the web.config file of Management.Api to Management.Repository, but Management.Repository doesn't have a web.config file since it's not hosted in IIS but the Management.Api is.

Note 2: Management.Api has a reference of Management.Repository, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

May i know how Management.Repository and Management.Api talk to each other?

If Management.Repository is a independent application without being hosted in iis, the possible way is to expose your web.config properties in Management.Api through web api and let Management.Repository grab the value?